# Temperature unit conversion in Rust

Tags: rust, unit-conversion

Below is a simple Rust program which inter-converts temperature between the Celsius scale and the Fahrenheit scale. It takes two inputs:

1. scale referring to the temperature scale of the next input
2. the value you you want to convert

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    loop {

        println!("Enter the temperature scale ('c' for Clesius and 'f' for Fahrenheit):");
        let mut choice: String = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut choice)
            .expect("Could not read the input!");

        let scale: char = match choice.trim() { // `\n` is also included in choice
            "c" => 'c',
            "C" => 'c',
            "f" => 'f',
            "F" => 'f',
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid scale chosen! Please try again.");
                continue
            }
        };

        println!("Enter the temperature:");
        let mut input: String = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut input)
            .expect("Could not read the input!");

        let temp: f64 = match input.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Please enter a number!");
                continue
            }
        };

        let result = match scale {
            'c' => c_to_f(temp),
            'f' => f_to_c(temp),
            _ => 0.0
        };

        println!("The converted temperature is: {result}");
    };
}

fn f_to_c (f: f64) -> f64 {
    (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
}

fn c_to_f (c: f64) -> f64 {
    c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
}
```

I starting learning Rust recently and wanted to know if the style that I have written in is good and if there are any code quality issues with my code.

Are there any good standards that I can read from or books/online resources where I can learn a few basic rules?

Comment: The code looks good to me. The only things I would change are the extra blank lines, and adding a semicolon after the `continue`s. In more performance critical examples, I would also declare the `String` outside the loop to not reallocate each time.

Comment: Cannot help with rust but fyi, typo: "Clesius".

Comment: @Marvin Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @ChayimRefaelFriedman Can't it be expected from a current compiler to do that kind of optimization? I think  for the purpose of readability the code as is is preferable to an optimized version as the string is reassigned every loop iteration, right?

Comment: Actually I don't program in Rust, but, given the simple nature of the two converter functions, wouldn't it make sense to store them as closures in a hash indexed by the commands, eliminating the `if` (given a valid hash key was there)? You could also map all invalid input to *one* error value, adding a third generic "error closure"...

Comment: @U.Windl The compiler probably can do this kind of optimization, but it doesn't in fact :) Maybe in the future.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 7):

## Use `cargo fmt`

or `rustfmt` to format your code. Then use clippy to lint it.
Many IDEs allow `cargo fmt`-ing the code when saving a file.

## Know your functions

`&str` does not only have a `trim()` method, but also `to_ascii_lowercase()`:

```rust
const ALLOWED_UNIS: [&str; 2] = ["c", "f"];

...


        
        if !ALLOWED_UNIS.contains(&choice.trim().to_ascii_lowercase().as_str()) {
            println!("Invalid scale chosen! Please try again.");
            continue;
        }
...
```

## Represent units as enum variants

You can use an enum to represent the two temperature units.
Since you're currently only using two, the conversion may be trivially implemented since we can default the target to the respective other unit:

```rust
enum Temperature {
    Fahrenheit(f64),
    Celsius(f64),
}

impl Temperature {
    pub fn convert(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            Self::Fahrenheit(fahrenheit) => Self::Celsius((fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0),
            Self::Celsius(celsius) => Self::Fahrenheit(celsius * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0),
        }
    }
}
```

## Implement useful traits

Since you parse the unit and the value seperately, you can implement `TryFrom` for a value / unit tuple to create a temperature variant:

```rust
impl TryFrom<(f64, &str)> for Temperature {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from((value, unit): (f64, &str)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match unit.trim().to_ascii_lowercase().as_str() {
            "c" => Ok(Self::Celsius(value)),
            "f" => Ok(Self::Fahrenheit(value)),
            _ => Err("unsupported unit"),
        }
    }
}
```

We can also implement `TryFrom` to parse the value from a string beforehand and then delegate to the other implementation above:

```rust
impl TryFrom<(&str, &str)> for Temperature {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from((value, unit): (&str, &str)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Self::try_from((
            value.trim().parse::<f64>().map_err(|_| "not a number")?,
            unit,
        ))
    }
}
```

And in order to properly display those, you can implement the `std::fmt::Display` trait:

```rust
impl Display for Temperature {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Celsius(value) => write!(f, "{} °C", value),
            Self::Fahrenheit(value) => write!(f, "{} °F", value),
        }
    }
}
```

## Putting it together

We have implemented the different temperature units as enum variants and allowed conversion between the two of them.
We also have outsourced some of the parsing into a `TryFrom` trait implementation.
Further we have implemented the `Display` trait.
Thus we have splitted up input, processing and output into separate components, though the input processing and parsing can still be improved upon:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::io;

enum Temperature {
    Celsius(f64),
    Fahrenheit(f64),
}

impl Temperature {
    pub fn convert(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            Self::Celsius(celsius) => Self::Fahrenheit(celsius * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0),
            Self::Fahrenheit(fahrenheit) => Self::Celsius((fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0),
        }
    }
}

impl Display for Temperature {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Celsius(value) => write!(f, "{value} °C"),
            Self::Fahrenheit(value) => write!(f, "{value} °F"),
        }
    }
}

impl TryFrom<(f64, &str)> for Temperature {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from((value, unit): (f64, &str)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match unit.trim().to_ascii_lowercase().as_str() {
            "c" => Ok(Self::Celsius(value)),
            "f" => Ok(Self::Fahrenheit(value)),
            _ => Err("unsupported unit"),
        }
    }
}

impl TryFrom<(&str, &str)> for Temperature {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from((value, unit): (&str, &str)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Self::try_from((
            value.trim().parse::<f64>().map_err(|_| "not a number")?,
            unit,
        ))
    }
}

fn main() {
    loop {
        println!("Enter the temperature scale ('c' for Celsius and 'f' for Fahrenheit):");
        let mut unit = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut unit)
            .expect("Could not read the input!");

        println!("Enter the temperature:");
        let mut value = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut value)
            .expect("Could not read the input!");

        match Temperature::try_from((value.as_str(), unit.as_str())) {
            Ok(temperature) => {
                println!("The converted temperature is: {}", temperature.convert());
            }
            Err(message) => eprintln!("{message}"),
        }
    }
}
```

**And with Chayim's hint included:**

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::io;

enum Temperature {
    Celsius(f64),
    Fahrenheit(f64),
}

impl Temperature {
    pub fn convert(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            Self::Celsius(celsius) => Self::Fahrenheit(celsius * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0),
            Self::Fahrenheit(fahrenheit) => Self::Celsius((fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0),
        }
    }
}

impl Display for Temperature {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Celsius(value) => write!(f, "{value} °C"),
            Self::Fahrenheit(value) => write!(f, "{value} °F"),
        }
    }
}

impl TryFrom<(f64, &str)> for Temperature {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from((value, unit): (f64, &str)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match unit.trim().to_ascii_lowercase().as_str() {
            "c" => Ok(Self::Celsius(value)),
            "f" => Ok(Self::Fahrenheit(value)),
            _ => Err("unsupported unit"),
        }
    }
}

impl TryFrom<(&str, &str)> for Temperature {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from((value, unit): (&str, &str)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Self::try_from((
            value.trim().parse::<f64>().map_err(|_| "not a number")?,
            unit,
        ))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut unit = String::new();
    let mut value = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("Enter the temperature scale ('c' for Celsius and 'f' for Fahrenheit):");
        unit.clear();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut unit)
            .expect("Could not read the input!");

        println!("Enter the temperature:");
        value.clear();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut value)
            .expect("Could not read the input!");

        match Temperature::try_from((value.as_str(), unit.as_str())) {
            Ok(temperature) => {
                println!("The converted temperature is: {}", temperature.convert());
            }
            Err(message) => eprintln!("{message}"),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the `enum`s the most useful, thank you.

Comment: For someone coming from an OO language, those pattern matches on the type of `self` look "wrong", since one of the fundamental rules of OO is that `self` knows its own type at all times, so it never needs to look it up, and invoking different behavior based on `self`'s type is just plain old message dispatch, which is built into OO. That's an interesting pattern to get used to, I imagine.

Comment: Some Rust concepts need some getting used to, indeed. I myself come from Python and Java. The fact that Rust does not support inheritance e.g., baffled me at first. But its other language concepts, especially the tagged unions aka. enums and trait system more than make up for it, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

### “Idiomatic” is in the Eye of the Beholder—But!

I’m also, for the purposes of this example, going to tweak the program so that it reads multiple lines of input, accepting any of the forms:

- `-0.0 F`, `0 C`, `0 f`, `0 c`
- `0F`, `0C`, `0f`, `0c`
- `0°F`, `0°C` (where `°` is U+00B0)
- `0℃` (where `℃` is U+2103)
- `0℉` (where `℉` is U+2109)

Rust supports many different programming styles, and there will often be a piece of code that’s a lot more elegant to express in an unusual way. Still: Some things are a lot more idiomatic than others.

Let’s start with:

#### Static Single Assignments

Rust made these the default, and makes you write `mut` if you want anything else.  Much of its syntax—including `match`, irrefutable `if let` patterns, the way `for` works, `while let` to re-initialize a loop variable on every iteration, and blocks as expressions—is there to allow you express the operations without needing mutable state.

Not only does this eliminate entire classes of logic errors that often crop up in early C, Rustc is built on top of LLVM, which converts all code to SSA form anyway (and the other experimental compiler projects also use backends whose intermediate representation is in SSA form).  So code written this way will usually compile quickly and optimize well.

Therefore, write an algorithm in Rust without `mut` if you can.  There are a couple of these in the code, so let’s refactor them:

```
let mut choice: String = String::new();
// ...
let mut input: String = String::new();
```

(Side note: you can leave out type annotations like `: String` when both the compiler and the human maintainer can easily infer them.  There’s no need to say `String` twice on the same line.)

What’s a good pattern to replace these with?

#### Iterator Expressions

Iterators are a big feature of Rust.  They’re designed to be used in fluent style, with either closures or helper functions.  Earlier, I said I was going to change the program to iterate over each line of input, and iterators are a great way to do that.  It’s such a common idiom that there’s a function in the standard library to turn a handle to standard input into an iterator over the lines of input:

```rs
use std::io::stdin;

pub fn main() {
    for line in stdin().lines() {
```

This actually returns a `Result` that is either a valid input line or an error.  To keep things simple, let’s panic on any read error, for now.

```rs
    let lines = stdin().lines().map(Result::unwrap); // Error recovery not implemented.

    for line in lines {
```

What’s the type of `lines`?  Some kind of iterator over `String`, so `line` is a `String`.  The compiler will figure it out.

#### Data Types

Here, there are two pieces of information we want to extract from each line, a scalar, and which scale it’s in.  You chose to represent the temperature as a `f64`.  That’s a great idea, and I’ll leave that part of your code alone.

There are two possible choices of unit, which naturally lends itself to an `enum`:

```rs
enum Scale {
    Celsius,
    Fahrenheit,
}
```

#### The Loop Body

Above, we started with a `for` loop that iterates over each `line` of input, as a `String`.  The “only” thing left is to fill in the body of this loop.

Although it would be possible to borrow the input line and extract each piece of information separately with a different call, it makes more sense here to parse the temperature into a tuple, with a scalar and a scale constant.  Since the string could be invalid, parsing it could fail.  Therefore, the result of a parse should be an `Option` type.  Finally, stringy inputs should normally be passed as `&str` if we aren’t going to consume or alter them.  This means the parse function will have the signature:

```
fn parse_temperature(line: &str) -> Option<(f64, Scale)>
```

(The compiler will actually enforce that function names should be `snake_case`, typenames should be `PascalCase` and constants should be `UPPERCASE`.)

We can fill in the body with `{todo!()}` for now, but we’ll come back to this later.

#### Exhaustive `match` Expressions

Once we’ve implemented the `parse_temperature` function, `main` can look something like this:

```rs
pub fn main() {
    println!("Enter a temperature, such as -32 F or 0.0°C.");

    let lines = stdin().lines().map(Result::unwrap); // Error recovery not implemented.

    for line in lines {
        match parse_temperature(&line) {
            Some((t, Scale::Celsius)) => {todo!()},
            Some((t, Scale::Fahrenheit)) => {todo!()},
            None => {todo!()},
        }
    }
}
```

Not only is this simple, it’s robust against changes.  If we later add a `Kelvin` scale, the compiler will notice that our `match` patterns no longer cover every case exhaustively, and tell us that we need to handle `Scale::Kelvin`.

#### Helper Functions

Rust makes heavy use of these, both on the right-hand side of static single assignments (what computer scientists call “phi functions,” because “phony functions” sounded too informal) and to pass to higher-order functions like `map`.  It’ll often be shorter and easier to write a shorthand like an `if` block, `match` statement or closure than a named function.

However you do it, composing your algorithms from small pieces that let you use patterns such as `map`, `fold` and railway-oriented programming is idiomatic Rust, and a large part of the standard library is written to enable this.

Let’s now come back to `parse_temperature`:

```
fn parse_temperature(line: &str) -> Option<(f64, Scale)>
```

What pieces does the standard library give us to turn an input string into a scalar and an `enum` representing its unit?  Well, we have `str::parse()`, which parses a string into an arbitrary type.  If we can extract from the original string the slices containing the scalar and the unit label, we can pass the first slice to `str::<f64>::parse`.  And if we `impl FromStr for Scale` (which we’ll come back to later), we will then be able to pass the second slice to `str::<Scale>::parse` as well.  So let’s write another helper, and call it `tokenize`.

Writing a pattern for `parse_temperature` that’s irrefutable (producing a value on every possible branch) would end up looking like a pyramid of doom, though:

```rs
    if let Some((scalar_str, unit_str)) = tokenize(line) {
        if let Ok(t) = scalar_str.parse() {
            if let Ok(u) = unit_str.trim_start().parse() {
                Some((t, u))
            } else {
                None
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    } else {
        None
    }
```

So you might (or might not) prefer a version without `else`.  Because we refactored this into a helper function, we can use `return` to write one:

```rs
    if let Some((scalar_str, unit_str)) = tokenize(line) {
        if let Ok(t) = scalar_str.parse() {
            if let Ok(u) = unit_str.trim_start().parse() {
                return Some((t, u));
            }
        }
    }

    None
}
```

Note that we don’t need to use any “turbofish operators” on this code: because one possible return value is `Some((t,u))`, the compiler can infer the types of `t` and `u` from the return type of the function, and apply that to the `if let` statements.

We now need to implement `tokenize`.  If we look through the documentation of the `str` type, we see two member functions that can do it: `str::find` locates the byte index of the first character in a string that matches a predicate, and `str::split_at` splits a string into two slices: the substring up to an index, and the substring starting at the index.  What predicate would make that work?  A predicate that returns `true` for the first character that is *not* part of a valid `f64`.  Decomposed that way, both pieces become simple:

```rs
    const fn not_fp(c: char) -> bool {
        match c {
            '+' | '-' | '.' | 'e' | '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' => {
                false
            }
            _ => true,
        }
    }

    fn tokenize(input: &str) -> Option<(&str, &str)> {
        input.find(not_fp).map(move |i| input.split_at(i))
    }
```

The implementation of `tokenize` uses a bit of railway-oriented style: if the `find` call returns `Some(index)`, `map` will pass `index` to the closure and wrap its result in `Some`.  If, on the other hand, `find` returns `None`, the algorithm will short-circuit and return `None`.

Also note that, even though we used borrows, we didn’t need any lifetime annotations.  In some other case, we might.  Here, since we borrowed our input and returned two borrowed slices as our outputs, the compiler assumed by default that the lifetimes were all the same.  Which is correct: the tokens are substrings of the input, with the same lifetime.

The `not_fp` function is a `match` expression like others we’ve seen.  One quirk of it is that it’s the only function in the program that can be declared `const`.  Every other one calls at least one trait function, which cannot be `const`; or does floating-point math, which cannot be `const` in LLVM; or calls several different non-`const` functions.  So, it’s a good idea to declare your functions `const fn` when you can, but here and in most other situations, it’s not actually useful.

#### Implement Useful Traits

As mentioned, we’ll need to implement the `FromStr` trait for parsing to a `Scale` to work.  One possible implementation is:

```rs
impl FromStr for Scale {
    type Err = ();
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, <Self as FromStr>::Err> {
        match s {
            "C" | "c" | "\u{00B0}C" | "\u{2103}" => Ok(Scale::Celsius),
            "F" | "f" | "\u{00B0}F" | "\u{2109}" => Ok(Scale::Fahrenheit),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}
```

It’s important to remember that Rust strings are *not* arrays of `char`, but contain UTF-8 byte data.  Fortunately, we can pattern-match them.

The most interesting decision here is that the trait allows us to return an arbitrary `Err` on failure.  But this program doesn’t actually need to know anything about the error, beyond the fact that one occurred, so we can just make our `Err` type the empty type, `()`.

Although we don’t actually use `==` or `.clone()` on `Scale` values in this program, it’s good practice to [derive trait implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/derive.html) that make sense for your type, in this case

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
```

### Putting it All Together

```rs
use std::io::stdin;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum Scale {
    Celsius,
    Fahrenheit,
}

impl FromStr for Scale {
    type Err = ();
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, <Self as FromStr>::Err> {
        match s {
            "C" | "c" | "\u{00B0}C" | "\u{2103}" => Ok(Scale::Celsius),
            "F" | "f" | "\u{00B0}F" | "\u{2109}" => Ok(Scale::Fahrenheit),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

fn parse_temperature(line: &str) -> Option<(f64, Scale)> {
    const fn not_fp(c: char) -> bool {
        match c {
            '+' | '-' | '.' | 'e' | '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' => {
                false
            }
            _ => true,
        }
    }

    fn tokenize(input: &str) -> Option<(&str, &str)> {
        input.find(not_fp).map(move |i| input.split_at(i))
    }

    if let Some((scalar_str, unit_str)) = tokenize(line) {
        if let Ok(t) = scalar_str.parse() {
            if let Ok(u) = unit_str.trim_start().parse() {
                return Some((t, u));
            }
        }
    }

    None
}

fn f_to_c(f: f64) -> f64 {
    (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
}

fn c_to_f(c: f64) -> f64 {
    c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("Enter a temperature, such as -32 F or 0.0°C.");

    let lines = stdin().lines().map(Result::unwrap); // Error recovery not implemented.

    for line in lines {
        match parse_temperature(&line) {
            Some((t, Scale::Celsius)) => {
                println!("{}°C is {}°F.", t, c_to_f(t));
            }
            Some((t, Scale::Fahrenheit)) => {
                println!("{}°F is {}°C.", t, f_to_c(t));
            }
            None => {
                println!("Parse error. Re-enter a temperature, such as -32 F or 0.0°C.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a [link to the Godbolt compiler explorer,](https://godbolt.org/z/nb91Gs6Gc) with testcases.

Comment: Will look into traits, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Remove the type annotations

You have annotated all of your local variables with their types (ex. `let mut input: String = ...`). Usually in Rust you let the compiler infer the type of local variables, unless adding in the type helps with readability or is necessary because the compiler is unable to infer its type.

### Use an enum for the scale

Instead of storing the scale as a character that is either `'f'` or `'c'`, create a enum for distinguishing the scales; for example:

```rust
enum Unit {
    Fahrenheit,
    Celsius,
}
```

This lets the compiler know that there are only two possible values, and checks that you handle them properly. This will let you remove the unused `_ => 0.0` branch in the conversion match.

#### Use or-patterns in the unit match

This:

```
        let scale: char = match choice.trim() { // `\n` is also included in choice
            "c" => 'c',
            "C" => 'c',
            "f" => 'f',
            "F" => 'f',
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid scale chosen! Please try again.");
                continue
            }
        };
```

Can be shortened to:

```
        let scale: char = match choice.trim() { // `\n` is also included in choice
            "c" | "C" => 'c',
            "f" | "F" => 'f',
            _ => {
                println!("Invalid scale chosen! Please try again.");
                continue
            }
        };
```

Since inputting "c" or "f" in either case should not affect the chosen units. Strings also have some case related methods.

#### Re-using the input buffer

If you create a single `String` variable before the loop, and use it with both `read_line` calls while `clear`ing it beforehand, the program will re-use the same buffer while reading, instead of allocating a new buffer each time like you are doing now. This is unlikely to affect the performance of your interactive app, but can make a difference in other situations that involve a lot of reading.

Comment: TIL the `|` - or-patterns, thanks.